# ! Error. The file name must end with xml

Tags: android

I'm a beginning developer. I have googled this problem and searched in stackoverflow. Although there were some similar questions answered my specific problem.
Here is the code that's getting this error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.android.happy18thbirthdayzane.MainActivity">


         <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:background="@drawable/black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="150dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Happy 18th Birthday!"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#d3a625"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="150dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Dear Zane"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#d3a625"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's the name of the file containing this XML?

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this error because a resource file is not ending with **.xml**.

Probably this `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    />
```

is causing this issue.

Make sure that your drawable file `black` is called **black.xml** and not only **black**.